# array push in multidimensional array when both object key same in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have twomultidimensional array in below format

```
$skillInfo = Array
(
    "Mechanical" => Array
        (
            "0" => 100
            "1" => 400
        )

    "Understanding" => Array
        (
            "0" => 200
        )

    "Application/Appreciation" => Array
        (
            "0" => 300
        )

);

$skillMaster = [
["skillID" => 1, "skillName" => "Mechanical"],
["skillID" => 2, "skillName" => "Understanding"],
["skillID" => 3, "skillName" => "Application/Appreciation"]
];
```

`$skillMaster` `skillName` is the same as `$skillInfo` keys, so we can replace `$skillInfo` keys from `$skillMaster` skillID.

Expected output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 100
            [1] => 400
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 200
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 300
        )

    )
```

my code

```
foreach($skillInfo as $key1 => $val1){
    $skillInfo[$key1][$skillMaster[$val1["skillID"]]] = $skillMaster[$val1["skillID"]] ?? [];
}
```

above code is not working as expected output, kindly anyone help me out.

Comment: `$val1` is a `$skillInfo` element, it doesn't have `skillID`.

Comment: skill name present `$skillInfo` array, i want to replace instead of name `skillID`

Comment: I know that's what you want to do. Why did you think `$val1['skillID']` would work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```php
foreach($skillMaster as $item){
  if(array_key_exists($item['skillName'], $skillInfo)){
        $skillInfo[$item['skillID']] = $skillInfo[$item['skillName']];
        unset($skillInfo[$item['skillName']]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Including an explanation of the changes you made would be helpful for both the OP and any future readers.